# List helm dependencies of an installed chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Helm offers the option of listing [dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency_list/) for a chart when browsing through its files.

So if I am above the folder of `my-chart`, I can perform

```
▶ helm dependency list my-chart
NAME    VERSION REPOSITORY          STATUS
common  0.12.6  file://../common/   ok
```

How can I get the dependencies for the **INSTALLED** chart, i.e. by retrieving this info from the actualy deployed version? (i.e. the one running on my cluster)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can retrieve this information only using documentation you provided. You should:

- Download the chart with `$ helm pull repo/name --untar` (skip this if you already have it)
- Go inside the chart directory
- Invoke command: `$ helm dependency list my-chart`

Alternatively you can inspect [requirements.yaml](https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Helm_Chart_requirements.yaml) for helm2 or [Chart.yaml](https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Helm_Chart_Chart.yaml#dependencies) for helm3, but you will find there only transitive dependencies :

> All applications, maybe with the exception of the most trivial,
> usually depend on other runtime components, such as web servers,
> caches, databases, etc. Helm supports modularization via a dependency
> mechanism, which allows to formally specify, manage and deploy
> dependencies as part of a Helm release. A Helm chart may declare
> dependencies, which are other Helm charts published in external
> repositories, conveniently packaged by people who presumably know the
> respective components well. The simples possible example is a chart A
> -- the dependent - that declared its reliance on a chart B - the dependency - by specifying chart B's “coordinates” (name, version and
> repository URL) as part of its own metadata. The exact way in which
> the dependencies are declared has evolved across Helm releases. For
> Helm 2 charts, the dependencies are declared in a dedicated
> requirements.yaml file, while for Helm 3 chart, the dependencies are
> declared as part of the chart manifest Chart.yaml. However, the way
> the dependencies are processed during installation has remained the
> same.

Good article: [Helm Dependencies](https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Helm_Dependencies)

Comment: Note that `helm dependency list my-chart` will only list 1st level  dependencies though